# JQuery ui - mobile: combine sortable with swipe event

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile, swipe, jquery-ui-sortable

Hello I'm trying to combine in a div the .sortable operation of jquery-ui with swipe evente on mobile device. Unfortunately when a div is .sortable it does not handle the 'swipe' event.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI doesn't support touchevents at the moment. You could use a plugin which converts the mouseevents as touch events here is link to the [Homepage](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) and [Github](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/). Thats the only way i know how to make jQuery UI widges touchable.